# Plot with two LabelStyle

Tags: plotting, labeling

I need to plot a graph using two different colors for the axis labels.

Not working example:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> {{Red, Black}}]
```

Any comment is welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `FrameStyle` or `FrameTicksStyle` with suboptions `FontColor`, `FontSize` etc. :

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["plot label", 22, "Subsection", Purple],
 FrameStyle -> {{Directive[FontColor -> Red, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 16],  Automatic}, 
  {Directive[FontColor -> Green, FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 20], Automatic}}]
```

[image]

We get the same output using `FrameTicksStyle` instead of `FrameStyle`:

```
FrameTicksStyle -> 
 {{Directive[FontColor -> Red, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 16], Automatic}, 
  {Directive[FontColor -> Green, FontFamily -> "Calibri",  FontSize -> 20], Automatic}}
```

You can also use the alternative syntax `FrameStyle ->{bottomstyle, leftstyle, topstyle, rightstyle}` to get the same output:

```
FrameStyle -> {Directive[FontColor -> Green, FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 20], 
               Directive[FontColor -> Red, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 16], 
               Automatic, Automatic}]
```

Similarly, for `FrameTicksStyle`.